Points hiding figures in Tikz package
I try to draw geometry in Overleaf by drawing one in GeoGebra and exporting ít to TikZ code, and then what I do is copy all the code and paste it into my Overleaf project, with added modification. But in GeoGebra, when label of a point overwrites lines then it also hides parts of that line (or circles). How can I do that in Overleaf with TikZ code? My figure has too much stuff in it, and I need this to make it look better (like in the picture label E obscures the lines AC and BD). Thanks!


Welcome. // I suggest to prepare a very simplified picture in GeoGebra, which still shows your problem in Tikz. Once you have, please post code and screenshots here, so we can see, try and improve. Thank you // If you want to do it in Tikz rather than GeoGebra, you should at least post a screenshot. THOUGH we do not convert bitmaps into Tikz code here, if you ask for links and pointers to helpful material, that should work here, too. Thank you

For the second point, this package may be interesting for you: https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide (click on the documentation and skim trough it) . You'll find examples via https://www.google.com/search?q=tikz-euclide+gallery AND clicking on pictures.

In the screenshot one would move the labels. In your complicated drawing that’s no option? // Click on the pdf link to open this https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide.pdf

Thank you. Now I added this picture to my post, and what I am trying is that how to make the label E hide the lines AC and BD like this picture with TikZ code, ít makes my picture look better. Thanks!
